# Android virtual device manager crashes with "double free or corruption"

Tags: android, android-studio

When i try to run any emulator I got:
[Android virtual device crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmI8A.png)

And a console i play Android studio in says:
`` *** Error in `/home/standy/Android/Sdk/tools/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00007f557c622fe0 *** ``

Any ideas?

Comment: getting same error.Did you find any solution?

Comment: same for me, anyone fixed this problem?

Comment: does the stack trace have nouveau_dri.so in it?

Answer (score 4):

1. Open Android Virtual Device Manager
2. Create new AVD,

   In the Verify configurations window (Virtual Device Configuration),
3. Go to `Emulated Performance > Graphics` and,
4. Select the `"Software (GLES)"` option