# Android Emulator crashes with SIGSEGV on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: android, android-emulator, kvm, ubuntu-18.04

Android Studio version:

Android Studio 3.1.2

Build #AI-173.4720617, built on April 14, 2018

It's installed from Ubuntu's snap store.
I installed the kvm using [1. Setting Up Android Studio on Ubuntu · uw-it-aca/spacescout-android Wiki](https://github.com/uw-it-aca/spacescout-android/wiki/1.-Setting-Up-Android-Studio-on-Ubuntu).
I tried what [Solve Android Studio AVD issue with Ubuntu distros - cialu.net](https://cialu.net/solve-android-studio-avd-issue-with-ubuntu-16-10/) suggested, but now the `lib64` folder doesn't contain `libstdc++`. The closest I could find is `libc++.so.1`, and I tried to install it using

```
sudo apt install libc++1
```

and link it similarly, but it just got my pc stuck.
I also looked at the threads linked by [Android emulator segmentation fault's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21437956/1346426) but they look old..

I also tried [How to solve Android Studio Emulator: libGL error on Ubuntu systems - cialu.net](https://cialu.net/android-studio-how-to-solve-emulator-libgl-error-on-ubuntu-systems/), but it didn't help.

I tried [Android Emulator is not starting in Ubuntu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22712342/1346426), using [How to install the NVIDIA drivers on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver Linux - LinuxConfig.org](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) to install the Nvidia drivers, but still not working. This is the output from `ubuntu-drivers devices`:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001401sv00001043sd0000854Dbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM206 [GeForce GTX 960]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

The only thing that worked is [Android virtual device manager crashes with “double free or corruption”'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45417478/1346426), but I want the hardware acceleration..

Can you please help me?

Comment: I've been trying to solve the same issue for a day now with no success. Have you made any progress since asking the question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After days of struggle I finally got it to work. The problem for me was that even if the OS was reporting Nvidia drivers as installed that was not the case. Checking with "lshw -c video" was showing that "nouveau" was in use regardless of how I was installing Nvidia ones - command line or using "Software & Updates" GUI.

What I've done was:

- install Ubuntu 18.04 without the option to install 3rd party software for graphics
- disable secure boot from BIOS. This was a key part which was preventing Nvidia drivers from being installed
- install drivers from command line with "sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390"

Comment: Thanks a lot, great work! I had problems debugging native code when using the software graphics, so that helped in that too!

Answer (score 6):

Another (easy) way to fix this is to follow the driver installation instructions given here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1033498

i.e.

> ```
> $ ubuntu-drivers devices
> $ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
> ```

Then reboot, and use:

`$ nvidia-smi`

To confirm the drivers installed correctly, where the output should be something like:

```
Sun Feb 17 16:28:49 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.77                 Driver Version: 390.77                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P400         Off  | 00000000:09:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 34%   26C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    199MiB /  1997MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1107      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            96MiB |
|    0      2646      G   ...or/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64    99MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the SIGSEGV occurs while switching between workspaces (virtual desktops), and appears to be a bug in gnome-shell and/or gjs, as reported [here on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1812527).  Give this bug some heat if you're affected.

Comment: In my case it was caused from the animation between work spaces. Disabling it solved the problem https://askubuntu.com/a/1083797/650195

Answer (score -1):

I downloaded a fresh version of Android Studio (AS) onto a new installation of Ubuntu
18.04 last month. I could compile my app inside AS but when I tried to run it on an
emulator (Next_5X_API_27 or Pixel_2_API_24) the emulator crashed with a SEGV fault.
I tried some things I saw on the web but nothing helped. I install Fedora 25 on a
space hard drive but with the same result.

Then I tried attaching my smartphone to the computer via USB and entered AS.  The
device came up when I tried to run my app and AS installed it on the device without
me asking and ran it correctly there. Now I can continue my project.

Comment: The question was about making the emulator work, I'm well aware I can use a real device, but for technical reasons, I needed the emulator